# How can I copy attachments from Opportunity object into Contract object?

Tags: trigger, opportunity, attachment

I have created a trigger that converts opportunities with stage equal to Closed/Won into a new Contract object. In this process, the trigger copies some information from the opportunity into the new contract (Account, Opportunity Name, etc) but I do not know how to copy the attachments related to the oppotunity into the new Contract. Somebody has already done this or something similar? Thanks in advance.

Follow is my trigger:

```
trigger CreatecontractonOppstageclosewon on Opportunity (after insert , after update) {

Set<Id> accId = new Set<Id>();
List<Opportunity> opplist = new List<Opportunity>();
List<contract> conrtlist = new List<contract>();


for(Opportunity opp : Trigger.new){
    if(opp.StageName == 'Closed Won'){
        Contract con = new Contract();

        if(opp.AccountId != NULL){
            con.AccountId = opp.AccountId;
        }

        con.Status = 'Draft';
        con.StartDate = System.Today();
        con.ContractTerm = 6;
        con.Importe__c = opp.Amount;
        con.Nombre_Oportunidad__c = opp.Name;
        conrtlist.add(con );
    }
}

if(conrtlist.size() > 0){
    insert conrtlist ;
}
```

}

Comment: Do you want to copy the attachments (now there will be identical attachments, one on opp, one on contract), or do you want to reparent it (the attachment is now attached to the contract and not the opportunity)

Comment: Another thought here would be (if you're using Chatter) to dispense with attachment and use the record feed and content version of each. That way you could just create a new post in the Contract that connects to the same content and the link persists to both records.

Comment: Hello, what I need is to copy the attachment that I already have in the opportunity object (the proposal document) into the contract object. As you mentioned, one on opp and one on the contract (the same). we are not using Chatter. Thanks